# Include mapped table in each entity from collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have following tables:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookBorrower> BookBorrowers { get; set; } = new List<BookBorrower>();
}

public class BookBorrower
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public int BorrowerId { get; set; }

    public Borrower Borrower { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsBookReturned { get; set; } = false;
}
```

First of all I have one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.
Now the question is how to include BookBorrower through the author.

I have those code

```
var author = await _db.Authors
            .Include(a => a.Books)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
```

author contains all of its book, but each book doesn't include its BookBorrowers property.

```
author.Books.BookBorrowers.Count // that's zero but I have enities in those table for those book.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ThenInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-2.1), for example:

```
var author = await _db.Authors
            .Include(a => a.Books)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.BookBorrowers) //Add this line
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
```

Comment: You can also do `.Include("Books.BookBorrowers")` to do both includes in one

Comment: @Chronicle Yes, but that method has no type safety, so I would never recommend it.

Comment: Omg man thanks you really much.... Actually I have tried with *ThenInclude*, but according to intellisens there wasn't such a property [link](http://prntscr.com/k8325m), but when I fill the full name of the property it works. ;o